# React Native AppState Blur doesnt work on navigation multitasking soft button click

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I am trying to hide app content when the user tries to navigate away from the app, like how banking apps or outlook works. I am using appstate inactive for ios, and appstate blur+focus for android. This works on Android when the user pulls down the notification panel or swipes up to multitasking tray or home through a gesture.

However, if the android phone has soft buttons for navigation instead of gestures, the app doesnt show the security screen on blur. I suppose react native loses control of the app too soon for that to happen. The blur event is still triggered, but the UI remains unchanged.

I have a useEffect in a custom hook that changes the state on blur, which triggers the UI update;

```
    const [appStateVisible, setAppStateVisible] = useState(true);
    const appState = useRef(AppState.currentState);    
    
    useEffect(() => {
            const androidFocusSubscription =
              Platform.OS === 'android' &&
              AppState.addEventListener('focus', () => {
                setAppStateVisible(true);
              });
            const androidBlurSubscription =
              Platform.OS === 'android' &&
              AppState.addEventListener('blur', () => {
                setAppStateVisible(false);
              });
        
            return () => {
              if (androidFocusSubscription && androidBlurSubscription) {
                androidFocusSubscription.remove();
                androidBlurSubscription.remove();
              }
            };
          }, []);

   return appStateVisible;
```

And then on App.tsx, I am calling this hook to decide whether to show the security image instead of the actual app content.

The alternative would be to use FLAG_SECURE in the java code to show a white screen when the app isnt active, but I want to show a custom screen with the app logo instead of a white screen.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.